# How to minimize recursion

Tags: python, tkinter, recursion, minesweeper

I'm trying to make minesweeper with tkinter in a really simple way but on the first click that break a lot of cells with no mines around it is kinda confusing. I tried checking all the cells around it by calling a function over and over again, there aren't that many cells to check but I keep getting a recursion error. How do I fix this?

```
def break_logic(now):
    global checked
    if BTNvals.get(now)==0: #check if the button has 0 mines around it
        checked.append(now)
        CanGo = check(now)[1]  #check surroundings 
        for _checked in CanGo:
            if _checked in checked:
                CanGo.remove(_checked)
            elif BTNvals.get(_checked)!=0:
                button_ids[_checked-1].destroy()
                CanGo.remove(_checked)
        for _cans in CanGo:
            button_ids[_cans-1].destroy()
            break_logic(_cans)  #recursion
```

0 means no mines around it.

[image: It breaks a bit but not all it's supposed to.]

It breaks a bit but not all it's supposed to.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: `BTNvals.get(now)` will never change during the loop.

Comment: @BryanOakley Why won't it ever change? is there a better way to do this? BTNvals is a dictionary btw.

Comment: Can you tell us which line inside that loop is the one you think changes the variable?

Comment: @BryanOakley Well, it calls the function with a different input. but I figured out a way to complete my minesweeper game already should I delete this question?